# abp deploy project abp framework in IIS

Tags: abp

I want to deploy ABP Blazor page into IIS, but when I login, I can't load page.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSg9E.png)

Please help me to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:  `abp generate-proxy -t csharp -u http://localhost:53929/`

Reference: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/API/Static-CSharp-API-Clients#static-c-api-client-proxies